How can I load a specific language server for a particular file extension?
I'm using emacs29 on linux.
At present, if I load a file with the extension '.tsx', and then do 'M-x lsp-mode' I get an error: 'Symbol’s value as variable is void: lsp-ada-project-file'
I assume that this means that lsp has connected the buffer to a language server for the ada language.
How can I connect the buffer to a language server that can parse .tsx files?

Load the library/package that defines variable lsp-ada-project-file. If that's your problem then this is a duplicate question and should be deleted.

Does this answer your question? Symbol's value as variable is void: shell-mode-map
